# What does the verb "exhaust" mean here?

Tags: meaning, verbs

But as readily as we grant this, it should be maintained with equal stress and emphasis, that this does not **exhaust the knowledge of** God; that it contains a spiritual reality which goes deeper than intellectual acumen, and employs the abstractions of dogma and doctrine merely as a means by which to clarify impressions received, the perceptions of the soul and spiritual experience.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know the referent of the subject "this". *A priori*, saying that something does not exhaust the knowledge of something means that there is still more to know about that something.

Comment: It means: exhaust God's knowledge and not: exhaust knowledge we have of God, though that is probably what they author meant to say. Sounds translated....

Comment: here is the link. https://opc.org/devotional.html?devotion_id=1729

Comment: I'm having trouble with the word exhaust.

Comment: It means to use up: my supply of food is exhausted, used up. I have exhausted (used up) my repertoire of jokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the aspects of "knowledge of God" that are described in the preceding paragraphs are not all the knowledge of God that is possible. Those are not "exhaustive" descriptions.

[American Heritage Dictionary "exhaust"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=exhaust)
tr.verb 3. To discuss or treat completely; cover thoroughly: *exhaust a topic.*

The previous paragraphs can be seen here;
[Googled source of quote](https://opc.org/devotional.html?devotion_id=1729)